# R: find identical combinations over multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a hard time explaining what I am looking for, but I try my best, so bear with me. I have the following data that contains pairs of individuals and a certain value per pair:

```
Col1  Col2  Value
A     B     90
E     F     90
B     A     50
C     D     50
F     E     90
```

What I want to do is find identical combinations (i.e. both A & B and B & A) and their respective values, and put them together. However, not all combinations are double in there (in my example, there is only C&D but no D&C).

I have tried to copy the data in a 2nd dataframe, then turn around col1 and col2 and then sort by col1. That gives me the following:

```
Col1  Col2  Value  Dummy
A     B     90     1
A     B     50     2
C     D     50     1
E     F     90     1
E     F     90     2
B     A     50     1
B     A     90     2
D     C     50     2
F     E     90     1
F     E     90     2
```

But I then still have both A&B and B&A in my data. Ideally I would like to end up with this:

```
Col1  Col2  Value
A     B     90
B     A     50
C     D     50
E     F     90
F     E     90
```

I hope my question is clear, but otherwise I am happy to try to explain myself better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base `R`, we order first  by the `min` column, then by the 1st column :

```
df[with(df,order(pmin(Col1,Col2),pmax(Col1,Col2),Col1)),]

#   Col1 Col2 Value
# 1    A    B    90
# 3    B    A    50
# 4    C    D    50
# 2    E    F    90
# 5    F    E    90
```

Thanks @akrun for the hint.

The `tidyverse` solution would be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(pmin(Col1,Col2),pmax(Col1,Col2),Col1)
```

previous solution :

```
df[order(
  apply(df[1:2],1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="")),
  df$Col1),]
```

data

```
df <- read.table(text=
"Col1  Col2  Value
A     B     90
E     F     90
B     A     50
C     D     50
F     E     90",h=T,strin=F
)
```

Comment: The previous solution: 
df[order(
  apply(df[1:2],1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="")),
  df$Col1),] 
seemed to work better for my data than: df[with(df,order(pmin(Col1,Col2),Col1)),]

Somehow the later sorts slightly differently, causing some of my pairs not to end up below each other (my real IDs are more complex than A, B etc so maybe that is why).

Would you mind explaining the previous solution? I see that apply somehow merges Col1 and 2 and order sorts it, but I am still not sure how it works.

Comment: Please check updated solution, it seems that I tried too hard to be smart :).

Comment: As for my first solution, I take the 2 first columns of the `data.frame` and apply a function line by line (that's what `apply(df[1:2],1` is for). This function sorts the two elements of this line and pastes them together. This sorted string is used to sort, in the `order` call, and ties are ordered by `Col1` (second argument of `order`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like `data %>% distinct(Col1, Col2, Value) %>% arrange(Col1)`

Comment: It works only by accident here, it won't put `A F` and `F A` next to each other